# Trouble between an injected iframe and other web page (Google, Gmail, Pdf)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Well i'm currently developping my Toolbar for Google Chrome as a Extension. The main principe is that i'm all the time injecting the toolbar as an iframe by using the Content Script.

But now i see a couple of bug with gmail, google map/search, pdf an maybe other that i've not yet see...

Let me explain, when i go on gmail, i don't see my toolbar at all...
When i open Google, it seems really normal :[image]

But then when i start a search my toolbar seems to overide the top link (web, images, videos, maps,...) I can't click on them anymore...

[image]

Next problem is when i'm trying to go on google map or trying to open a PDF, it seems to give the same css to these web pages from my toolbar...

Google Maps :

[image]

PDF :

[image]

Hope i where clear enough, do not hesitate to ask me question if necessary ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've find a good solution to resolve the problem with PDF and Google Map it was a problem on my CSS.

About the google Search now it works perfectly by setting the body webpage as a fixed page like NeXXeus tell me but there is still a problem.

Check this out :
[image]

[image]

EDIT : We don't really see, the argument select/deselect is top: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use absolute/fixed positioning and style attributes? Using style attributes would remove the issue of the possible spread of CSS.

Comment: I've tried, it resolve some problems but it add other problems so it didn't seems to be the good one...

Comment: Using position fixed would fix the overlap issue.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the toolbar from pdf, you could write something that removes the element when on pdf?